# How to install ejabberd on AWS linux server?

Tags: php, linux, amazon-web-services, xmpp, ejabberd

I am installing the ejabberd on AWS linux server.I tried a lot but i did not get any success.

I am following the instructions and commands from below Url

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ejabberd-xmpp-server-on-ubuntu

when i am executing below command to install ejabberd

```
apt-get -y install ejabberd
```

this showing me the error

```
E: Package 'ejabberd' has no installation candidate
```

Answer (score 1):

Download `ejabberd` package according to your OS
For CentOS:
`https://www.process-one.net/downloads/downloads-action.php?file=/ejabberd/16.03/ejabberd-16.03-0.x86_64.rpm`
For Debian:
`https://www.process-one.net/downloads/downloads-action.php?file=/ejabberd/16.03/ejabberd_16.03-0_amd64.deb`
For Mac OS X:
`https://www.process-one.net/downloads/downloads-action.php?file=/ejabberd/16.03/ejabberd-16.03-osx-installer.app.zip`
For Windows:
`https://www.process-one.net/downloads/downloads-action.php?file=/ejabberd/16.03/ejabberd-16.03-windows-installer.exe`

Install & Enjoy!